# Require command line argument for script to run

Tags: linux, bash, arguments

I'm trying to require a script to only run if the command line argument provided is a specific text file called dailyUserProcs.20181203 in the same directory as the script. I am also running Putty.

Currently I am requiring any input to run the script, shown below.

```
if [ -z "$1" ] then
echo" No argument"
exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Why require that specific argument if it's static?

Comment: Honestly I agree there is no reason for it, but sadly this is for a class assignment and is required.

Comment: So you've learned about test ([) and $1... what did you try for comparing $1 to a string?

Comment: Wow, thanks for the comment. Just figured it out after reading your comment. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test if a file exists, use `-f`.
To test if two strings are equal, use `==` (and similarly not equal is `!=`).
To negate something, use `!`.
To logical or two tests, use `||`.
Putting this all together, you get

```
if [ ! -f "$1" ] || [ "$1" != "dailyUserProcs.20181203" ]; then
    echo Invalid Argument
    exit 1
fi
echo Argument exists and is correct
# ... rest of code
```

This can all be found by typing `info test`, and reading the documentation.